# How to configure server location for surveymonkey

Tags: surveymonkey

In which countries are the Servers from surveymonkey located? 
Is it possible to configure the location of the server, where the customers answers to the surveys from surveymonkey are stored?
The security department of our german company only accepts servers, which are located in western europe to be sure, that european right protects the customers data.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a client in the EU. They had to accept SM as there was no European equivalent with multiple language and question type support . After the survey we were instructed to delete the server data after download.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer via Mail from surveymonkey-Support - I copy it here for other users with the same question:
"Unfortunately, at this time, all of our survey data is stored on servers located within the US, and we wouldn't be able to host this information on your servers or any outside servers."